# Function overload object hirearchy

Tags: c++, oop

In c++, if you have the following

```
struct Base
{

};

struct Derived1 : Base
{

};

struct Derived2 : Derived1
{

};

struct Derived3 : Derived2
{
};

void f(const Derived2&)
{
    std::cout << "Derived2" << std::endl;
}

void f(const Derived1&)
{
    std::cout << "Derived1" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f(Derived3());
    return 0;
}
```

What reason is it that f(Derived3()) calls "void f(const Derived2&)"? Is it because it is closer in the object hierarchy to Derived3 than Derived1 is?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [overload resolution rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) for c++.

When trying to resolve which function to call, if there is no direct match in argument types, the compiler has to rank the conversions that would be needed to the arguments in order to choose the best candidate.

For conversions relating to objects in an inheritance hierarchy:

```
3) If Mid is derived (directly or indirectly) from Base, and Derived is derived (directly or indirectly) from Mid
a) Derived* to Mid* is better than Derived* to Base*
b) Derived to Mid& is better than Derived to Base&
c) Base::* to Mid::* is better than Base::* to Derived::*
d) Derived to Mid is better than Derived to Base
e) Mid* to Base* is better than Derived* to Base*
f) Mid to Base& is better than Derived to Base&
g) Mid::* to Derived::* is better than Base::* to Derived::*
h) Mid to Base is better than Derived to Base
```

Case b) applies to your example.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what is meant by c) Base::* to Mid::* is better than Base::* to Derived::*